# Why are my delayed_job jobs re-running even though I tell them not to?

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I have this in my initializer:

```
Delayed::Job.const_set( "MAX_ATTEMPTS", 1 )
```

However, my jobs are still re-running after failure, seemingly completely ignoring this setting.

What might be going on?

**more info**

Here's what I'm observing: jobs with a populated "last error" field and an "attempts" number of more than 1 (10+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered I was reading the old/wrong wiki. The correct way to set this is

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your dbms table "delayed_jobs" for records (jobs) that still exist after the job "fails". The job will be re-run if the record is still there. -- If it shows that the "attempts" is non-zero then you know that your constant setting isn't working right.

Another guess is that the job's "failure," for some reason, is not being caught by DelayedJob. -- In that case, the "attempts" would still be at 0.

Debug by examining the delayed_job/lib/delayed/job.rb file. Esp the self.workoff method when one of your jobs "fail"

**Added** @John, I don't use MAX_ATTEMPTS. To debug, look in the gem to see where it is used. Sounds like the problem is that the job is being handled in the normal way rather than limiting attempts to 1. Use the debugger or a logging stmt to ensure that your MAX_ATTEMPTS setting is getting through.

**Remember** that the DelayedJobs jobs runner is not a full Rails program. So it could be that your initializer setting is not being run. Look into the script you're using to run the jobs runner.

Comment: I just added some more info... Are you familiar with the MAX_ATTEMPTS setting and how it is intended to behave? Thanks for the pointer to that file, I'll check it out...

Comment: FWIW, setting MAX_ATTEMPTS in the initializer as such is the way recommended by the DJ docs/wiki.